# Getting "Incorrect syntax near 'cR' exception while executing dynamic sql

Tags: sql-server, dynamic

The below query is trying to get count of driver datable, where  am getting exception while calling from c# solution.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_AtmosPurge_PersonalInfoPurgeCount]  
    (@cPurgeQueue VARCHAR,  
     @dStartDate VARCHAR,  
     @dEndDate VARCHAR,  
     @iClientID VARCHAR,  
     @TableName VARCHAR)  
AS  
BEGIN  
    DECLARE  @sql NVARCHAR(512)   

    SET @sql = N'SELECT COUNT(1)   
                 FROM   
                     (SELECT 
                          RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY D.cCitationNumber ORDER BY L.iPurgeLogId  DESC) AS ROWNUM,  
                          D.cCitationNumber, 
                          D.vcFirstName, D.vcMiddleName, D.vcLastName, 
                          D.vcNameSuffix, D.vcAddress1, D.vcAddress2,  
                          D.vcCity, D.vcStateOrProvince, D.vcZipOrPostalCode, 
                          D.cDriverLicenseNo, D.vcDriverLicenseState, D.vcTelephoneNo,  
                          D.sdDateOfBirth, D.cGender, D.cEyeColor, D.cHairColor,
                          D.cWeight, D.cHeight, D.cRace, D.tNoOfPriorViolations,  
                          D.cLicenseClass, D.sdLicIssue, D.sdLicExpire, D.iCountyID, 
                          L.iPurgeLogId   
                      FROM ' + QuoteName(@TableName) + ' D (NOLOCK)  
                      INNER JOIN tblPurgeLog L (NOLOCK) ON L.cCitationNumber = D.cCitationNumber  
                      WHERE L.dViolationDate BETWEEN ' + QuoteName(@dStartDate) + 'AND ' + QuoteName(@dEndDate) + '  
                        AND L.iclientid ='+ QuoteName(@iClientID) +'  
                        AND LTRIM(RTRIM(vcPurgeQueue)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(' + QuoteName(@cPurgeQueue) + ')) ) AS D   
                 WHERE ROWNUM = 1 '   

    EXECUTE (@sql)  
END
```

Comment: There is no 'cR' except in the `D.cRace` field.  Is this sql causing the exception?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Comment: And also: **WHY** are your parameters which are **obviously** dates of type `VARCHAR` ?!?!?!? Use the **most appropriate** datatype - always - and for a date, that's not definitely not `VARCHAR`!! Use `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)`

Comment: can you please PRINT @sql and run that sql to see the real error

Comment: All your parameters are currently declared as strings of length **1 CHARACTER** because you did not provide a length. Refer to what marc_s linked. And one must wonder why you need the table name to be dynamic when the query itself assumes and relies on that particular table have very specific columns. And there is no magic in the use of the NOLOCK hint - get rid of it until you understand the implications of its use.

Answer (score 0):

Your @sql Variable is too small. Change your declaration to

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000)
```

and you will be good. You can also try removing the formatting by spaces in the statement so it looks like:

```
    SET @sql = N'SELECT COUNT(1)   
FROM   
(SELECT 
RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY D.cCitationNumber ORDER BY L.iPurgeLogId  DESC) AS ROWNUM,  
D.cCitationNumber, 
D.vcFirstName, D.vcMiddleName, D.vcLastName, 
D.vcNameSuffix, D.vcAddress1, D.vcAddress2,  
D.vcCity, D.vcStateOrProvince, D.vcZipOrPostalCode, 
D.cDriverLicenseNo, D.vcDriverLicenseState, D.vcTelephoneNo,  
D.sdDateOfBirth, D.cGender, D.cEyeColor, D.cHairColor,
D.cWeight, D.cHeight, D.cRace, D.tNoOfPriorViolations,  
D.cLicenseClass, D.sdLicIssue, D.sdLicExpire, D.iCountyID, 
L.iPurgeLogId   
FROM ' + QuoteName(@TableName) + ' D (NOLOCK)  
INNER JOIN tblPurgeLog L (NOLOCK) ON L.cCitationNumber = D.cCitationNumber  
WHERE L.dViolationDate BETWEEN ' + QuoteName(@dStartDate) + 'AND ' + QuoteName(@dEndDate) + '  
AND L.iclientid ='+ QuoteName(@iClientID) +'  
AND LTRIM(RTRIM(vcPurgeQueue)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(' + QuoteName(@cPurgeQueue) + ')) ) AS D   
WHERE ROWNUM = 1 '
```

But in this case, the SQL is still too long for a 512 character variable.  It cuts off before I hit the FROM statement, at about `D.cLicenseClass, D.sdLicIssue, D.sdLicExpire,`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, now am getting incorrect syntax at "INNER".Can you please look into it

Comment: Is it getting the error during concatenation of the SQL, or when you try and execute the SQL? Try outputting the SQL statement before executing it. Also, output your passed-in parameters before execution of the statement, so you can confirm the entered data.